# How to update a separate variable and add it to another variable during each loop iteration? (running calculator iteration problem)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a running calculator. After every loop, lap should be updated with "extra" and summed together with what I have ran already.

> ran = 2.45 lap = .45 extra = 0.05

The formula is this:

> 2.45 + .45 = first loop.
>
> 2.90 + .5 = second loop.
>
> 3.4 + .55 = third loop.
>
> 3.95 + .60 = fourth loop.
>
> 4.55 + .65 = fifth loop.

During each iteration of the for loop, the "ran" variable should add lap and extra.

lap should update lap + extra.

extra should remain constant.

this is the code I have so far:

```
ran = 2.45;
let lap = .45
const extra = .05;

var arra = [];
var sum = 0;


 for (let i = 1; i <=5; i++) {
     
   ran+= lap;
   
   
   
   arra.push(Math.round(ran*100)/100) 
   
   };

 
console.log(arra)
```

All I can manage to do so far is add ran to lap. What I need to do instead, is update lap during each loop, while maintaining extra as a constant and summing this up with ran.

> loop 1 lap = .45 loop2 lap = .5 loop3 lap = .55 loop4 lap = .6
> loop5 lap = .65

Answer (score 1):

You could increment the loop value with extra for each loop.

```js
let
    ran = 2.45,
    lap = .45,
    extra = 0.5;
    
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ran += lap;
    lap += extra;
    console.log(ran.toFixed(2));
}
```